# How can I use store in slice?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I want to use store in my action/reducer slice file and I want to call series of thunk which dispatch API response in to store, to dispatch next thunk I required some data from store how can I do that?

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import store from '../store'

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: "counter",
  initialState: {
    value: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => {
      state.value += 1;
    },
    decrement: (state) => {
      state.value -= 1;
    },
    incrementByAmount: (state, action) => {
      state.value += action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } = counterSlice.actions;

export const incrementAsync = (amount) => (dispatch) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    dispatch(incrementByAmount(amount));
  }, 1000);
};

export const sendIncrementValueToServer= () => (dispatch) => {
  value = store.getState().counter.value //Is this possible to do here?
  const response = //POST API request to send value
};

export const selectCount = (state) => state.counter.value;

export default counterSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thunks already have access to `getState` as the second argument, so you just need to change it to:

```js
// Thunk signature is (dispatch, getState)
export const sendIncrementValueToServer= () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  value = getState().counter.value
  const response = //POST API request to send value
};
```

Comment: Hey Mark, with the getState call, can we update another part of the state with it? Or should we call the action that updates that piece of state?

Comment: What you mean by "update another part of the state"?  Remember that [many reducers may respond to the same action](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#allow-many-reducers-to-respond-to-the-same-action), and [actions do not have a 1:1 correspondence with reducers](https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#is-there-always-a-one-to-one-mapping-between-reducers-and-actions).